# How to build a list of tuples from a list of numbers?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list 'x' consisted of some numbers and ideally I wish to obtain a list like 'a'

```
x = [12, 37, 64, 159, 205, 225, 239, 252, 257]
a = [(12,37),(37,64),(64,159),(159,205),(205,225),(225,239),(239,252),(252,257)]
```

I have the following code but it does not seem to do the right thing:

```
for i in zip(x[::2], x[1::2]):
    print(i)
```

I got the results like:

```
(12, 37)
(64, 159)
(205, 225)
(239, 252)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access each element by index:

```
x = [12, 37, 64, 159, 205, 225, 239, 252, 257] 
new_x = [[x[i], x[i+1]] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
```

Output:

```
[[12, 37], [37, 64], [64, 159], [159, 205], [205, 225], [225, 239], [239, 252], [252, 257]]
```

However, a `zip`-based solution requires simple list slicing:

```
new_x = list(zip(x, x[1:]))
```

Output:

```
[(12, 37), (37, 64), (64, 159), (159, 205), (205, 225), (225, 239), (239, 252), (252, 257)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = [12, 37, 64, 159, 205, 225, 239, 252, 257]
print([i for i in zip(x[::1], x[1::])])
```

Output:

```
[(12, 37), (37, 64), (64, 159), (159, 205), (205, 225), (225, 239), (239, 252), (252, 257)]
```

In slicing you need to be careful with step number as you used 2 as step number it will always used 2nd element for it's position.
so instead writing `x[::2]` you are supposed to write `x[::1]` now the default step for slice is 1 hence you don't need to mention it so you can write only `x` instead of `x[::1]` and for next you can just write `x[1:]` instead of `x[1::]`